# Vagrant- Hyper-V: The following settings shouldn't exist: customize, gui

Tags: vagrant, hyper-v

I was trying to run vagrant of version 2.2.5 in windows 10 with Hyper-V version 10.0 
I was getting this error

```
There are errors in the configuration of this machine.
Please fix the following errors and try again:
Hyper-V:
* The following settings shouldn't exist: customize, gui
```

I had checked other simlar questions but nothing seemed to help.

My vagrant file

```
$script = <<-SCRIPT

echo "cd /vagrant" >> /home/vagrant/.profile
echo "All good!!"
SCRIPT

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|


    config.vm.box = "bento/ubuntu-16.04"

    config.ssh.username = 'vagrant'
    config.ssh.password = 'vagrant'
    config.ssh.insert_key = 'true'


    # Ports foward
    # For CouchDB Container
    config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 5984, host: 5984
    # Zookeeper
    #config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 2181, host: 2181
    # For Kafka Broker
    #config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 9092, host: 9092
    # For Kafka Manager
    config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 9000, host: 9000
    # This gets executed for both vm1 & vm2
    #config.vm.provision "shell", inline:  "echo 'All good'"
    config.vm.provision "shell", inline:  $script

    config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
      vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "2048", "--cpus", "1"]
      vb.gui = false
    end

    config.vm.provider :hyperv do |hv|
      hv.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "2048", "--cpus", "1"]
      hv.gui = false
    end


  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove this section

```
config.vm.provider :hyperv do |hv|
      hv.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "2048", "--cpus", "1"]
      hv.gui = false
    end
```

all together. Those parameters are specific to VirtualBox

You can look at [hyperv specific settings](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/hyperv/configuration.html) that you can add to this section if you need